# Open new mail window with data and allow editing

Tags: java, email-attachments

I am generating an email with an attached file, but I want to open the default email client in order to edit the email.

I'm trying with API Desktop:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileEML);
```

When `fileEML` is the .eml file created with the email information.

I have tried with `Desktop.getDesktop().mail(URI)` but this option doesn't support the attachment files.

Any option how to implement it?
Is there any API that implements this option?